# What useful security reports can be extracted from a Windows-based machine and its related logs?

Tags: windows, attack-prevention, audit, logging

What logs and event IDs should I be paying attention to when looking at a Windows-based machine  (workstation, server, Domain Controller)?

Assuming I can aggregate them into a report what information should I include in Standard Operating Procedures (SOP) reviews?

Answer (score 2):

For log analysis OSSEC has a few files with MS specific rules designed to extract interesting security events.  To see individual rules one can peruse these files:

> [/var/ossec/rules]# ls -l ms*
>   -r-xr-x--- 1 root ossec 31423 Sep  7  2010 msauth_rules.xml
>   -r-xr-x--- 1 root ossec 11978 Sep  7  2010 ms_dhcp_rules.xml
>   -r-xr-x--- 1 root ossec  1547 Sep  7  2010 ms-exchange_rules.xml
>   -r-xr-x--- 1 root ossec  2077 Sep  7  2010 ms_ftpd_rules.xml
>   -r-xr-x--- 1 root ossec  2190 Sep  7  2010 ms-se_rules.xml

For the latest copy of these rules files you can head over to bitbucket -> https://bitbucket.org/dcid/ossec-hids

(under Source -> ossec-hids / etc / rules /)